# glossaries, fancyhdr: acronym not replaced properly

Tags: header-footer, glossaries, fancyhdr

In the following example the acronym is not replaced properly in the header and look like in this screenshot:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
  \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \usepackage[toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \newacronym{VOIP}{VoIP}{Voice over IP}
  \makeglossaries
  \renewcommand{\glossarymark}[1]{}
\begin{document}
  \chapter{Sample Chapter \gls{VOIP}}
  text \gls{VOIP}
  \printglossaries
\end{document}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/5764) You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Answer (score 1):

Beside using the optional argument you can also use commands like `\glsentrydesc` (described the in documentation as "commands without links"):

```
   \documentclass{book}
      \usepackage{fancyhdr}
      \usepackage[toc,nonumberlist]{glossaries}
      \pagestyle{fancy}
      \newacronym{VOIP}{VoIP}{Voice over IP}
      \makeglossaries
      \renewcommand{\glossarymark}[1]{}
    \begin{document}
      \tableofcontents
      \chapter{Sample Chapter \glsentrydesc{VOIP} (\glsentrytext{VOIP})}
      text \gls{VOIP}
      \printglossaries
    \end{document}
```

Comment: The problem with this is it does not work with the smallcaps option with `glossaries` since `\glsentrytext` gives \textsc{Voip} as a string. Any work arounds?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the "short/ToC title" of the `\chapter` command to obtain a more appropriate header: `\chapter[Sample Chapter VOIP]{Sample Chapter \gls{VOIP}}`

[image]